# How to deactivate and activate external javascript src value?

Tags: javascript, html, toggle, src

I want to deactivate and activate a particular external JS script when clicking on a menu item. When user clicks the menu item, little bugs stop crawling the screen. By clicking again the bugs come back. I needs this to work without reloading the page. My initial thought was to activate a function that changes my script src value from "myFile.js" to "" (empty) and then back again.

```js
function toggleBugs () {
    document.getElementById("myJSFile.js").src = "";
    }
```

```html
<li>
<a id="toggleBugs" href="#toggleBugs" onclick="toggleBugs()">Activate/Deactivate Bugs</a>
</li>
```

But apparently src value can't be empty. I know this has to be simple, but thus far I haven't got it.

Comment: This should be done within the function itself, you're trying to hack around coding it correctly.  Post your toggleBugs function

Comment: The function has been posted. It is just that single line of code. On clicking user calls that function. That is as far as I got.

Comment: No, I mean the functions inside the 'myJSFile.js'

Comment: Well, that is a large JS file with many functions. I think you are referring to the functions that activate the bugs. There are none to deactivate, though.

Comment: Here it is: // ATIVAÇÃO E DESATIVAÇÃO DOS BICHINHOS
  
// default fruit fly bug:
new BugController({
}); 

// default spiders:
new SpiderController({
});

Comment: Correct, you should create one to remove be bugs.  Removing the included file wouldn't do that anyway.

Comment: Here is the link for the full bug code from Auz: https://github.com/Auz/Bug

Comment: Thank you, TheValyreanGroup. That is the question: What sort of code can I use to deactivate and activate them clicking on that menu item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation for that external library.  You start the bugs with `initialize()` and remove them all with `end()`.  So to make a toggle function, you can do this.

```
var areBugsOn = false;

function toggleBugs(){
    if(areBugsOn){
         end();
         areBugsOn = false;
    }else{
         initialize();
         areBugsOn = true;
    }
 }
```